# How to call Oracle SQL query using bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

How to call a sql query using bash shell script. I tried the below but seems there is some syntax error:

```
#!/bin/sh
LogDir='/albt/dev/test1/test2/logs' # log file 
USER='test'     #Enter Oracle DB User name
PASSWORD='test'  #Enter Oracle DB Password
SID='test'        #Enter SID
sqlplus -s << EOF > ${LogDir}/sql.log 
${DB_USER_NAME}/${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_SID} 
SELECT count(1) FROM dual; #  SQL script here to get executed  
EOF 
var=$(SELECT count(1) FROM dual)
```

I'm getting - unexpected token error

```
#!/bin/sh
user="test"
pass="test"
var="$1"
sqlplus -S $user/$pass <<EOF
 SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE username=$var;  
 exit;
EOF
```

I'm getting -  sqlplus: command not found -- when I run the above script

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: What do you mean by "seems ther eis some syntax error" ? What is the exact error ? Also, your last line does not seem to be correct.

Comment: Yes it is throwing syntax error

Comment: Please remove the _bash_ tag. It does not look like bash would be involved in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first script, one error is in the use of `count(1)`. The whole line is

```
var=$(SELECT count(1) FROM dual)
```

This means that the shell is supposed to execute a program named `SELECT` with the parameters *count(1)*, *FROM*  and *dual*, and stores its stdout into the variable `var`. I think you want instead to feed a SELECT command into sqlplus, i.e. something like

```
var=$(sqlplus .... )
```

In your second script, the error message simply means that *sqlplus* can not be found in your path. Either add it to the PATH or provide the absolute path to the command explicitly.

Comment: I need to trigger the sql query. Whatever output of it is should be passed to the json.